# Error when changing pages with Summary Links web parts (SP2010)

Tags: deployment

When making any changes on pages with Summary Links web part and after deployment of the site I get the message:
Access Denied saving Web Part properties: ether the web Part is embedded directly in the page, or you do not have sufficient permission to save properties (Web part 'Summary Links')"

Best regards

Tore

Answer (score 1):

Did you check out the page first? Since versioning is now enabled for webpart changes you need to check out/in changes if versiong and publishing is enabled.